# Compress image like Whatsapp and Facebook using Android

Tags: android, image, facebook, compression, whatsapp

I have tried this code for converting `image` it's work fine for title bit size, but I want to a resize of image dynamic, like Whatsapp and Facebook.
in `Whatsapp` `4` to `5 MB` image are compressed into `KB` so how can i do this?

```
 public String compressImage(String imageUri) {

    String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

    float maxHeight = 816.0f;
    float maxWidth = 612.0f;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {               imgRatio = maxHeight /     actualHeight;                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);                   actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;             } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        }
    }

     options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth,     actualHeight);

    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    try {
         bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth,     actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY -     bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

     ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filename = getFilename();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

       scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filename;

}

public String getFilename() {
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),     "MyFolder/Images");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.mkdirs();
}
String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
return uriSting;

}

private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
    Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null,     null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index =     cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
}
public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int     reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
    final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) reqHeight);
    final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
    inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;          }       final float totalPixels = width * height;       final float     totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;       while (totalPixels /         (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
    inSampleSize++;
    }

return inSampleSize;
}
```

This code converting image but in my project requirement like this.

Comment: What is the problem with above code ?

Comment: means you want to crop image like fb and wtsp and also compress ?

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi nothing problem in above code but i want to compress image like fb & wtsp. in size to particular like i upload 2mb pic so its compress into 1 mb  like that to compress

Comment: @BhaveshRangani yes like that i want to work. so how to do .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- for cropping image you can use this [lib](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage)
- and for compressing the image you can use this code also.

  ```
  public Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath) {

  BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

  // The new size we want to scale to
  final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

  // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
  int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
  int scale = 1;
  while (true) {
      if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
          break;
      width_tmp /= 2;
      height_tmp /= 2;
      scale *= 2;
  }

  // Decode with inSampleSize
  BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  o2.inSampleSize = scale;
  Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

   ExifInterface exif;
      try 
      {               
          exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
          int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                  ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

          int rotate = 0;
          switch (exifOrientation) {
          case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
              rotate = 90;
              break;

          case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
              rotate = 180;
              break;

          case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
              rotate = 270;
              break;
          }

          if (rotate != 0) {
              int w = image.getWidth();
              int h = image.getHeight();

              // Setting pre rotate
              Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
              mtx.preRotate(rotate);

              // Rotating Bitmap & convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
              image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);

          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
               return null;
      }
      return image.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
  }
  ```

Comment: this code is create image less than 1mb . and if you want to specify your own size than change the size in this int variable 'final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024; '

Comment: i want image height & Width is same but just only compress the image size.

Comment: means you want to reduce only size of image and don't want to reduce height and width?

Comment: only reducing size of image without reducing height or width can damage the quality of image in that case best way is i have given to you in my answer.

Comment: but what happen at all to upload the image into data base is so storage space.